# React form resets but writeups on the form does not clear up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to reset my form to its Original state(i.e. a state with nothing on it, totally blank) after clicking the submit button. In my code I set all variables back to its initial values, this appears to work but the writeups on the form still remains after clicking the submit button. I will appreciate your answer, thank you. Pls What you see here is not the full code but the part of the code snippets that matter.

```
    const [totalAmountIn, setTotalAmountIn] = useState(0);
    const [amountRecieved, setAmountRecieved] = useState(0);
    const [balanceDue, setBalanceDue] = useState(0);
    const [itemDescription, setItemDescription] = useState("");
    const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([]);
    const [moneyInData, setMoneyInData] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [themessage, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);


    let totalSellingPrice = 0;
    const handleTotalAmtInChange = (e) => {
        setTotalAmountIn(e.target.value);
        console.log(totalAmountIn)
    }
    const handleAmountRecievedChange = (e) => {
        setAmountRecieved(e.target.value);
    }
    const handleItemDescription = (e) => {
        setItemDescription(e.target.value);
    }

 let handleSaveItem = () => {
        const newItemData = { productName, sellingPriceOfTotal, quantityCount, sellingPrice };
        setNewItems([...newItems, newItemData]);
        console.log(newItemData);

    }

let handleSaveMonyIn = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        //setBalanceDue(balanceSet);
        if (totalAmountIn === 0 || itemDescription === "") {
            setError(true);
            setMessage("Enter Amount and Item Description");
            setOpen(true)
        } else if (totalSellingPrice > totalAmountIn) {
            console.log(totalSellingPrice);
            setError(true);
            setMessage("Total Selling Prices cannot be bigger than Total amount");
            setOpen(true)
        }

        else {
            const newMoneyInData = { totalAmountIn, amountRecieved, balanceDue, newItems, itemDescription };
            setMoneyInData([...moneyInData, newMoneyInData]);
           
            setTotalAmountIn(0);
            setAmountRecieved(0);
            setBalanceDue(0);
            setItemDescription('');
            setNewItems([]);
            console.log(newMoneyInData);
        }
        
        //totalAmountIn, amountRecieved, balanceDue, itemDescription, newItems
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually show the form we're trying to clear so I am assuming it is structured like below. Check if you have a default value assigned too. Set the clearForm to your submit button. Let me know if this helps or not.

```
<button onClick={clearForm}> Submit </button>


clearForm = () => { 
  document.getElementById("form-id").reset();
}


 <form id="form-id">
   <input />
 </form>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: WOW!!! It worked like magic, was thinking as I was using react a whole lot of Core javascripts principles like getElementById might not be useful that much here. You saved me of one full day of several trials, thanks much!!!

Comment: No problem, React is great but it's nothing with out good old js! Good luck and happy coding!